# How do you Configure Package Management System (YUM) for MongoDB

Tags: linux, centos, configuration, yum

On the site ([mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/)) it lists ...

```
Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo file to hold the following configuration information for the MongoDB repository:
```

then...

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I am confused as to what the name of the second set of directions should be, ie what file name?

Comment: I'm sorry, I would like to help you, but I cannot understand your question. Can you elaborate more, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to do my best to help you, using the informations you gave us.
Assuming you have a 64 bit CPU (`uname -p` to check this, x86_64=64 bit), you have to just add the repository as you stated, than issue this commands:

```
yum clean all
```

this will clean your yum cache and you should be able to see the new mondodb repository in the list

```
yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server
```

with this command you will install mongodb and all the dependencies, if needed.

```
service mongod start
```

and finally you can start your new service.

If you have a 32 bit CPU, use instead this repository:

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

and just run the same commands above.